# Unexpected result using grep to filter ls output

Tags: grep, ls

I am currently working on an issue using `grep` and `ls`. The goal is to list all lines that are link files in my current directory. I have 3 link files in my directory, but when I execute my command it only shows one.

Here is what I'm typing:

```
ls -lR | grep l*
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Instead of parsing the output of `ls`, use `find . -type l`.

Answer (score 1):

Your pipeline has a few issues.

1. Parsing the output of `ls` [is not a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (see also [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/315749)). Its format is not standardized and file names can contain any combination of bytes except for NUL and `/`. Hence, it doesn't guarantee to list file names in an unambiguous form. The frequently given example involves newline characters (note how invoking `ls` in different ways may lead to distinct, possibly ambiguous, results):

   ```sh
   $ touch 'foo
   > bar'
   $ ls -1
   'foo'$'\n''bar'
   $ ls | cat
   foo
   bar
   ```

   Are `foo` and `bar` two distinct files or two parts of the same file name?

   The safe way to recursively search a directory for files of a given type is [`find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/find.html).
2. The unescaped string `l*` is interpreted by the shell as a [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) expression. It is expanded to the list of file names (by a broad [definition of "file"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_164)) that start with `l` in the current directory.

   ```sh
   # In a directory you created for testing purposes
   $ rm *; touch foo; ln -s foo link1; ln -s foo link2; ln -s foo link3
   $ set -x; ls -lR | grep l*
   + ls -lR
   + grep link1 link2 link3
   ```

   The `xtrace` shell option (i.e. `set -x`, available in several shells and specified by [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)) is useful to show the effect of filename expansion (globbing): `l*` expands to `link1 link2 link3` and `grep` is therefore searching for the string `link1` in the content of `foo` (through the symbolic links `link2` and `link3`). ([`grep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/grep.html) doesn't read standard input when it is given a list of file names after the pattern to search).

   If you happen to have just *one* file whose name starts with `l`:

   ```sh
   # In a directory you created for testing purposes
   $ rm *; touch foo; ln -s foo link1; ln -s foo Link2; ln -s foo Link3
   $ set -x; ls -lR | grep l*
   + ls -lR
   + grep link1
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group 3 May  1 03:04 link1 -> foo
   ```

   Then `grep` searches its standard input (the output of `ls`) for the string `link1`, here matching one line. (Reading standard input is what `grep` does when it is given no file names, or if a file-name argument is `-`).

   You should [quote](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02) literal strings meant to be passed as arguments to prevent the shell from performing filename expansion. As an alternative, where supported by your shell, filename expansion can be disabled using `set -f`.
3. If no file name in the current directory starts with `l`, the globbing expression is left untouched and passed to `grep` as the first positional argument. `grep` will then interpret it as a regular expression (defaulting to the [BRE variant](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03)) which reads "for any line of input, match an *optional* `l` (anywhere)", effectively matching anything:

   ```sh
   # In a directory you created for testing purposes
   $ rm *; touch foo
   $ ls -lR
   .:
   total 0
   -rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 May  1 02:49 foo
   $ set -x; ls -lR | grep l*
   + ls -lR
   + grep 'l*'
   .:
   total 0
   -rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 May  1 03:14 foo
   ```

   To match a string that starts with a literal `l` you need an anchored expression: `grep '^l'`.

Comment: i appreciate the feedback, very thorough.

Comment: @CrowMan55 Glad to see I've been of help.

Answer (score 1):

[@NasirRiley is on the right track](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583680/unexpected-result-using-grep-to-filter-ls-output#comment1086866_583680). To list the symlinks in the current directory run `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type l`. Test:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/bar baz
$ ln --symbolic foo/bar ban
$ ln --symbolic bar foo/bat # symlink in subdirectory, should be ignored
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type l
./ban
```

Comment: As he is using `ls -lR`, I figured that he wanted to search through the subdirectories as well. If he doesn't, then your answer is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, the command you were looking for is:

```
ls -l | grep '^l'
```

The quotes aren't necessarily needed.

The removal of the `-R` option on `ls` is because you specified that you wanted the current directory, not the directory tree.

And either way, the answers pointing you to `find` are probably a better solution.

Comment: wow that worked, thanks. I see the mistake